# Does compression increase performance?

Tags: java, performance, compression, io

I'm using java and have many pictures to load from the hard drive.

Generally, is it faster to use highly compressed pictures (that probably take long to decompress) or not compressed pictures (that probably take long to load, but no time is spent on decompreesing the pictures)?

Comment: Depends on picture sizes, compression algorithms, number of pictures, etc. Be more specific.

Comment: size: 150px x 100 px, format: png, number: several 1000

Comment: @kohlehydrat: The only way to obtain an answer is to *measure* on your particular platform.  You need to find out how much time is spent doing disk IO, and how much time would be spent doing decompression.  And you also need to work out how much you care about lossy compression artifacts.  No-one here can answer this question for you!

Comment: PNG is by itself compressed with DEFLATE. I dont think it will make a big improvement it you can "externally" compress it 5-10%% more, it will take a bigger toll uncomressing... IMHO

Comment: are you loading these to display as part of a UI or loading them to send out to clients as a web / ftp server?

Comment: You can run `pngcrush` once on your images, than they have about the minimal size possible for PNGs. (This takes a while, though.) Applying an external compression to compressed images is not useful, if you don't have many very similar images - and even then it is only useful if you always load all (or many) of them, and are using a compression which works file-overlapping (i.e. tar.gz or such).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for most questions like this, I would recommend you measuring this.

It'll be dependent on so much. Your pictures, your algorithm, your deployment platform (CPUs, disk space etc.). I don't think anyone could give a remotely accurate idea without being familiar with the above variables.

Note (also) that premature optimisation is (often) the root of all evil. It's often advisable to choose the simplest solution (here - using no compression) and start to look at this as/when performance becomes an issue.

Comment: Agreed, but two comments: Compressing already compressed image (PNG) is always wrong, no measurement needed. Compressing uncompressed pictures (BMP) is nearly always right, since much more of them fit in the cache (main memory, disk cluster, whatever) which makes the access much faster (measuring or switching to better format recommended).